# Gremlin Driver Cannot Deserialize Response from Germlin Servier Running Bitsy Database

Tags: serialization, kotlin, gremlin, tinkerpop3, bitsy

I'm running a gremlin server with bitsy using the conf and properties file given in the github repo (https://github.com/lambdazen/bitsy/tree/master/src/test/resources/gremlin-server). I have, of course, changed `dbPath` to an appropriate path.

My client is a kotlin application running gremlin console. I have no problem executing queries that result in string or map values, for example:

```
val encodedPasswd = getg().V().has("user", "login", login).values<String>("password").next()
```

However, when attempting to get vertices from queries:

```
val user = getg().V().has("user", "login", login).next()
```

I get a deserialization error:

```
[gremlin-driver-loop-1] WARN org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGraphSONMessageSerializerV2d0 - Response [PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 7446, widx: 7446, cap: 7446)] could not be deserialized by org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGraphSONMessageSerializerV2d0.
org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.message.ResponseMessage` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"requestId":"5e78c0ba-64d2-4b31-8b04-262c3fa2b3b8","status":{"message":"Error during serialization: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: com.lambdazen.bitsy.store.VertexBean[\"id\"])","code":599,"attributes":{"@type":"g:Map","@value":["stackTrace","org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: com.lambdazen.bi"[truncated 6946 bytes]; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1451)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1027)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1297)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONTypeDeserializer.deserialize(GraphSONTypeDeserializer.java:212)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(GraphSONTypeDeserializer.java:86)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1178)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:68)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3091)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGraphSONMessageSerializerV2d0.deserializeResponse(AbstractGraphSONMessageSerializerV2d0.java:134)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.decode(WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.java:50)
...
```

Cluster construction:

```
var cluster = Cluster.build()
    .serializer (
        GryoMessageSerializerV3d0 (
            GryoMapper.build()
                .addRegistry(BitsyIoRegistryV3d0.instance())
        )
    )
    .serializer (
        GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0 (
            GraphSONMapper.build()
                .addRegistry(BitsyIoRegistryV3d0.instance())
            .create()
        )
    )
.create()
```

and traversal source construction:

```
fun getg() : GraphTraversalSource {
    return EmptyGraph.instance().traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster))
}
```

Relevant parts of my gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation('org.apache.tinkerpop:gremlin-driver:3.3.4')
    implementation("com.lambdazen.bitsy:bitsy:3.1.0")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.+")
}
```

Why can't the driver deserialise messages from the server? What do I change to allow it to?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure, but I'm guessing that Bitsy lacks full support for GraphSON 3.0. If you look at its `IoRegistry` implementation it registers no custom serializers for GraphSON (just for Gryo):

https://github.com/lambdazen/bitsy/blob/c0dd4b6c9d6dc9987d0168c91417eb04d80bf712/src/main/java/com/lambdazen/bitsy/BitsyIoRegistryV3d0.java

I assume that's the reason why you get a serialization error. If you switch to just using Gryo (which is probably recommended to some extent since you are on the JVM with Kotlin) I imagine you won't have this problem.

Note that your `Cluster` object definition is not configuring the way you expect either. By calling `serializer()` twice (i.e. once for Gryo and once for GraphSON) you actually overwrite the Gryo configuration and simply configure the object to work with GraphSON.

So, I think you would just do this:

```
var cluster = Cluster.build()
    .serializer (
        GryoMessageSerializerV3d0 (
            GryoMapper.build()
                .addRegistry(BitsyIoRegistryV3d0.instance())
        )
    )
.create()
```